# Finding controls within Devexpress ASPxGridView

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have a code that contains an ASPxGridView and a ASPxCheckBox and Label within in like:

---

```
    <dx:ASPxGridView ID="gvTableSearchHomes" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlHomes" Width="341px"
CssClass="tableViewSearchGrid" ClientInstanceName="gvTableSearchHomes"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowsCache="false" KeyFieldName="ID">
<%--<Columns>--%>
    <%-- DXCOMMENT: Within ASPxGridView, add a column whose values will participate in filtering --%>
    <%--<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Address">
        <PropertiesTextEdit NullText="Search your home"></PropertiesTextEdit>
        <Settings AllowAutoFilterTextInputTimer="True" AutoFilterCondition="Contains" />
    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
</Columns>--%>
    <Templates>
     <%--DXCOMMENT: Configure the grid's DataRow template in accordance with data source fields --%>
    <DataRow>
        <div class="gvItem">
            <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="ChkBookList" runat="server"></dx:ASPxCheckBox>
            <dx:ASPxLabel ID="Address" runat="server" CssClass="address" Text='<%# Utils.ExtractFirstRow(Eval("Address")) %>' />
            <%--<p><dx:ASPxLabel ID="Address2" runat="server" CssClass="address2" Text='<%# Utils.ExtractSecondRow(Eval("Address")) %>' /></p>
            <p><dx:ASPxLabel ID="Price" runat="server" CssClass="price" Text='<%# Utils.GetPrice(Eval("Price")) %>' /></p>--%>
        </div>
    </DataRow>
</Templates>
<SettingsPager Visible="false" PageSize="1000" />
<Settings ShowVerticalScrollBar="True" ShowFilterRow="true" ShowColumnHeaders="false"/>
<SettingsBehavior AutoExpandAllGroups="true" AllowSelectSingleRowOnly="true" AllowSelectByRowClick="true"/>
<ClientSideEvents 
    Init="function(){ hr.TableViewLandscape_Adjust(); }" 
    EndCallback="function(){ hr.TableViewLandscape_Adjust(); }"
    SelectionChanged="OnGvTableSearchHomesSelectedChanged" />
<Styles>
    <SelectedRow ForeColor="White"></SelectedRow>
</Styles>
```

---

I am not able to access these cotnrols through C# code. Can anybody help me. Please

Comment: You should clean your code before posting it. Remove comments and code that isn't relevant for your question.

Comment: Update your code-behind code where you are trying to access the controls.. on which grid view event you are trying to access the controls.

Comment: Why don't you contact the DevExpress guys regarding your inquiry?

Comment: @Mikhail DevExpress support is useless in most cases. All you get is a link to their trivial examples which have nothing to do with actual problem,

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation methods](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridViewClassMethodsTopic) to find controls in different gridview templates. 
e.g. [ASPxGridView.FindRowTemplateControl Method](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_FindRowTemplateControltopic)

Source: http://developmentsolutionsjunction.blogspot.in/2011/11/find-controls-in-dataitemtemplate-of.html

//markup

```
    <dx:ASPxGridView ID="grvTest" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
          OnHtmlRowPrepared="grvTest_HtmlRowPrepared" OnHtmlRowCreated="grvTest_HtmlRowCreated">
          <Columns>
              <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="RowID" Name="colRowID" VisibleIndex="0" Width="20px">
                  <DataItemTemplate>
                       <dx:ASPxLabel ID="lblRowID" runat="server" Text='Label'>
                      </dx:ASPxLabel>
                 </DataItemTemplate>
</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

//accessing template control in code-behind

```
protected void grvTest_HtmlRowCreated(object sender, ASPxGridViewTableRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowType != GridViewRowType.Data) return;

            ASPxLabel label = grvTest.FindRowCellTemplateControl(e.VisibleIndex, null,
            "lblRowID") as ASPxLabel;
            label.Text = (e.VisibleIndex + 1).ToString();
        }
```

example code:

```
ASPxGridView grid = (ASPxGridView)sender;

ASPxPageControl myPages = grid.FindEditFormTemplateControl("CityEditTabs") 
                                                              as ASPxPageControl;
```

References:
[How can I write events for the controls used in my Grid templates](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/A1140.aspx)
[Some GridView code snippets to understand gridview concepts](http://developmentsolutionsjunction.blogspot.in/search/label/DevExpress)

Identify the VisibleIndex or RowHandle to get the control in particular template that you have created in your markup.

Hope above example will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Niranjan, are you sure that this still works? KB article you refer to is written for old DevEx grid library.

Comment: @Filip: why not these thing will not change suddenly, even version 8 threads will let you reach somewhat near to the solution. I have mentioned the upgraded gridview reference that will help to get the control at various gridview server side events.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. You are using ASPxGrid.Items in your example and current DevEx components doesn't include ASPxGrid. Also, ASPxGridView doesn't have Items collection property.

Comment: Well i have done clean of old version of grid control.. Well new version of grid controls are accessed within the gridview events or the repositoryitem's own event.

Answer (score 0):

thanks I solved mi problem. I put this

```
Protected Sub GvEncuesta_HtmlRowCreated(sender As Object, e As ASPxGridViewTableRowEventArgs)
    If (e.RowType <> GridViewRowType.Data) Then Return

    Try
        Dim cmbRespuesas As ASPxComboBox = GvEncuesta.FindRowCellTemplateControl(e.VisibleIndex, Nothing, "ASPxCmbRespuestas")

        cmbRespuesas.IncrementalFilteringMode = IncrementalFilteringMode.Contains
        cmbRespuesas.Visible = True
        cmbRespuesas.DataSource = wcfCap.RetrieveRespuestaEncuestaxEstado(1)
        cmbRespuesas.ValueField = "Cod_Respuesta"
        cmbRespuesas.TextField = "Nombre_Respuesta"
        cmbRespuesas.DataBindItems()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```