# Devexpress Get gridview cell as hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink, devexpress

I want to loop and edit the hyperlinks in my devexpress's gridview

```
    protected void ASPxGridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ASPxGridView1.VisibleRowCount; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = ASPxGridView1.GetDataRow(i);
            ASPxHyperLink hl = row["MyColumnName"] as ASPxHyperLink;
            hl.Text = "something";
        }
    }
```

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error points to hl.text = "something";

How do I convert the row into a hyperlink properly? row["MyColumnName"].ToString() returns the text of the cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer these:
[Find controls in the DataItem template of ASPxGridView column](http://developmentsolutionsjunction.blogspot.in/2011/11/find-controls-in-dataitemtemplate-of.html)
[The general technique of using the Init/Load event handler](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18282/the-general-technique-of-using-the-init-load-event-handler)
[Finding controls within Devexpress ASPxGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103688/finding-controls-within-devexpress-aspxgridview)

Either you can use the HtmlRowCreated event then you can fine control with various method provided by ASPxGridView API. There is another way that you can use the Init event of the Hyperlink control and at this event you can customize the control and  also review the "[How to access controls used as my Grid templates](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/A1141.aspx)" article for details.

```
protected void ASPxHyperLink1_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
ASPxHyperLink myLink =(ASPxHyperLink)sender;
int key = Convert.ToInt32(ASPxGridView.GetDetailRowKeyValue(myLink.NamingContainer));
}
```

References:
[ASPxGridView Hyperlink NavigateUrl at Runtime](http://developmentsolutionsjunction.blogspot.in/2011/11/aspxgridview-hyperlink-navigateurl-at.html)